# How to add a button which can make text 'bold' in a Text Area in an HTML page,?

Tags: html, css

I am making an Online Text editor, and want to add a button above the text area, which can make the selected text and/or the text to be written as bold. For a better description, I want to add a bold button as it is above the Stack overflow text area.

Here is the Screen shot of what I want to add. [The Stack Overflow Ask question Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEMzs.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I am new to Stack overflow, I watched the tour. Can u please tell me, what wrong did i do?

Comment: At a minimum you must ask a question. Your description is clear but you never state what you want. You must provide some insight into what you've tried, constraints you have, what didn't work, what research you've done, where you've looked for answers already. Please don't expect someone to give you code without making some effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well looking at what you want to achieve, you need something more like a WYSIWYG editor library or plugin. which comes alone with all this inbuilt. most are highly customisable and there is no need to reinvent the wheel. wasting your time on debugging. The only thing you might have to do is fiugure out how to add the plugin or library to your webpage which is mostly easier and even if difficult will take much less time as compared to starting from scratch. Most of which are opensource and you can just grab the codes from github
Below are a number of them which you can use.I normally personally prefer CKeditor any day.

1. [CKEDITOR](http://ckeditor.com/)
2. [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/)
3. [Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor)
4. [Summernote](http://summernote.org/)
5. [Aloha Editor](http://www.alohaeditor.org/)

Comment: Thankyou for your solution mate. I got the required response. :-)